# Get an error when creating voice channel not sure what to do

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, nextcord

I'm creating a command that will create voice channels, It takes a few arguments from the user and makes a voice channel with it. Here is the code -

```
##TEST CREATE VC
@bot.command(name="createvoice")
async def createvoice(ctx, name = "Voice Channel", user_limit = 5,):
    guild = ctx.message.author.guild
    await guild.create_voice_channel(name, int(user_limit))
```

It works normal with 1 argument, but the issue occurs when I add more arguments such as user_limit or any other. So i type .createvoice testname 5 and I get the error -  **nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Guild.create_voice_channel() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**

Anyone knows how to fix it and how to make it create the channel in a specific category?

Comment: FYI instead of `ctx.message.author.guild`, just use `ctx.guild`. Taking the detour through the message is unnecessary, and then going through the _author_ is even more unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to provide a name**. When I provided a name it worked for me. To do this change

```
await guild.create_voice_channel(name, user_limit=5)
```

to

```
await guild.create_voice_channel(name="VOICE_CHANNEL_NAME", user_limit=5)
```

and replace `VOICE_CHANNEL_NAME` to your wanted voice channel name.

If you want to have the user choose the name simply replace `name="VOICE_CHANNEL_NAME"` with `name=name` so you would have

```
await guild.create_voice_channel(name=name, user_limit=5)
```

For a code that is **completely customisable** for the user use this *(where the user can pick category, name and user limit for a voice channel)*:

```
@bot.command(name="createvoice")
async def createvoice(ctx, category_name: discord.CategoryChannel, name = "Voice Channel", user_limit=5):
    guild = ctx.message.author.guild
    await guild.create_voice_channel(category=category_name, name=name, user_limit=user_limit)
```

Now the user can send something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ElK6.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD55C.png) will happen.

*I hope this helps :)*

Comment: But i need the user to be able to add a name user limit etc. So like .createvoice Name (user limit) 6 and others

Comment: I have edited the post (look at the bottom bit.) Do you also want the user to be able to choose the user_limit too?

Comment: Oh i got it! Thank you so much! But by any change do you know how to make the voice channel in a curtain category?

Comment: No problem. There we go; it took some investigating but I have found how. Look at the bottom bit to see. Remember to mark this as the answer if this is sufficient :)